# Deploying Laravel projects on Hostinger

Tags: laravel

I am trying to deploy a Laravel application on Hostinger - how can I go about it? I tried using the deployment method of 000webhostapp on it because they are somehow alike but it ended up giving me

> Error 500 response

I followed the procedures from this page to host it on Hostinger but it ended up giving me

> Error 500

https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this still needed since it's an old thread, however, if anybody will reach this question you have two options:

1. Put all folders outside public_html (one level above) and put your public/ folder's content to public_html only. Make sure the index.php path is correct.
2. Put all folders inside public_html. Create .htaccess file in public_html (if there is no any) and paste this code to make public/ folder as a default:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If paths are set correctly, both methods will work on Hostinger Shared and Cloud plans.

Comment: Again after long time
if i have folder structure like this 
    main-domain
    sub-domain-1
    sub-domain-2 inside public_html then
how to point to main domain with correct url. i mean without /main-domain/public

Answer (score 0):

The guide you referenced is the most awful guide I've ever seen, follow this instead.

https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e